# Upgraded NginX from 1.18.0 to 1.23.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Wordpress page URLs all non-functional post-upgrade

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

Once I finished doing the above the associated wordpress site's permalinks stopped working.

The wordpress site itself and all .php and .html files render fine, it is only that any sub-page (except for the home page) is now invalid and clicking any wordpress page link generates 404 errors on the Wordpress site.

Curiously, the wordpress "/admin" page still works 100% correctly under both NginX 1.18.0 and NginX 1.23.0 - with the admin back-end ALSO using what looks like permalinks...

This is my /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf for the new instance, I used the same file as was working on my 1.18.0 install on my 1.23.0 Ubuntu 20.04 based install:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    root /var/www/wordpress;

    server_name www.myserver.com

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    autoindex off;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/wordpress;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Several suggested fixes have already been incorporated for fixing permalinks in Wordpress under Nginx, e. g. these are Google-ed suggestions:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
```

iso just

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

and adding

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

to the **location ~ .php$** block.

Nothing works. Any sub-page URL I try to access on the site gives a 404.

Sub-page URLs are typical wordpress URLs, e.g.

```
www.myserver.com/home/top-content
www.myserver.com/home/get-in-thouch
```

etc. - these are all now broken and result in 404s if clicked when this wordpress site is deployed under NginX 1.23.0 in Ubuntu 20.04.

The above worked correctly with NginX 1.18.0 and Wordpress 6.0.1, NginX 1.23.0 cannot / does not provide Wordpress permalink functionality with the above **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** config.

What am I missing to get WordPress permalink functionality back under NginX 1.23.0 - clearly there is some differences in how that is configured in NginX 1.23.0 vs. NginX 1.18.0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was solved by adding

```
if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
```

to my **/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** config file, then restarting NginX and php8.1-fpm.

E. g. my **/etc/nginx.conf.d/default.conf** file under NginX 1.23.0. needs the above added to provide the same wordpress permalink functionality as I had with the same PHP and Wordpress instances under NginX 1.18.0.

My **/etc/nginx.conf.d/default.conf** in a NginX 1.23.0 wordpress permalink compatible state is

```
server {
    listen       80;

    root /var/www/wordpress;

    server_name www.msbmanagement.co.za;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    autoindex off;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/wordpress;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args =404;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    #THIS WAS REQUIRED TO BE ADDED FOR NGINX 1.23.0 BEGIN
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
       rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }
    #THIS WAS REQUIRED TO BE ADDED FOR NGINX 1.23.0 END

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone. Apparently quite a few differences are extant as regards wordpress permalink URL rewriting in NginX 1.18.0 vs NginX 1.23.0.